# Find Out Welcome Page via SharePoint Web Services

Tags: publishing-site, web-services

Does anybody know if/how it is possible to retrieve a SharePoint site's Welcome Page via the built-in Web Services? This is for both 2007/2010.

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Screen scrape the data?

Comment: It always makes more sense to explain what you are trying to *do*, not just the technical question, which might not even be the *right* question!

Answer (score 1):

The only web services that run on both SharePoint 2007 and 2010 are the ASMX soap-based web services. The only web service that might have supported this to my knowledge was the Webs.asmx, but I took a look and the GetWeb() method returns the  url (without default page). I don't believe any of the ASMX web services will provide this value.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you are trying to do. If you simply want to grab the home page for a site, you can use jQuery's AJAX function to request it by simply passing in the URL of the site.